# alert the value of an element on click of link Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

How can I alert the `value` of the element `onclick` of link here? A simple alert is not working inside this and I don't want to use `console.log()`

```
var row = '';
$.each(result, function(index, element) {
    row += '<tr>';
    row += '<td>' + '<a href="" onclick="alert the value here(alert(element.Name)">' + "Link" + '</a>' + '</td>';
});
```

Comment: `onclick="alert(this.name)"` This seems moot though, as the `a` element you attach this event to has no `name` or `value` property, so I'm not sure of the behaviour you're expecting.

Comment: I think you need `row += '<td>' + '<a href="" onclick="alert(\'' + element.Name + '\')">' + "Link" + '</a>' + '</td>';`

Comment: Is that proper @Satpal?? because its not working for me! Any changes in the quotes used " ' '??

Answer (score 0):

Save the value in a "data" element in the link itself and then later use that value at runtime when you make the click: [example on fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aej5zurs/1/)

```
var row = '';
$.each(result, function(index, element) {
row+='<tr>';
row += '<td>' + '<a data-name=' + element.Name+ ' href=""      onclick="alert($(this).data(Name));">' + "Link" + '</a>' + '</td>';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use onclick attribute in ajax loaded content.

Declare in attribute id.

for Example:

```
var row = '';
$.each(result, function(index, element) {
row+='<tr>';
row += '<td>' + '<a id="XXX" href="">' + "Link" + '</a>' + '</td>';
});


$(document).on('click',"#XXX", function() {
alert("Alert working..!");
});
```

Comment: the same id' for multiple elements??

Comment: it is preferreble to add it in a data-xxxx attribute: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp

Comment: @amtd `XXX` is obviously a placeholder.

Comment: @atmd `id="XXX"` is also current value.

Comment: it might not be 'obvious' to the OP. if they all have different id's do you add click event on each id? no, but the OP might not be aware of that